# how can I change background behind my spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the standard login Activity created with eclipse
New-->other--> Android Activity --> New Login Activity

(you can try to create the same activity... I am using "Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 1" )

I changed all background activity/fragments in :  #0099cc

But when I pass from an activity to another i see the backgound white like in the images.

Can you help me?

I think the important code is the follow:

showProgress(true);

```
    /**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    **I tried in this way**
        mLoginStatusView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(show ?1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); }
        });
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(show ? 0:1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
        }
                });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

in login.xml layout

```
        <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#0099cc" />
```

in attrs.xml

```
<!--
     Declare custom theme attributes that allow changing which styles are
     used for button bars depending on the API level.
     ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle is new as of API 11 so this is
     necessary to support previous API levels.
-->
<declare-styleable name="ButtonBarContainerTheme">
    <attr name="buttonBarStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="buttonBarButtonStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

[image: Loging activity]

[image: where I would like change the background]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem (after trying to manage the style in many ways) addying a simple row:

getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));

```
    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.

    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write your own style for the whole application, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) are the API guides from Google.